# Remote desktop connection for mac - no "option" to choose screen size

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I have a MAC machine, the OS is 10.7.4, 27' monitor, and I installed a software named "Remote desktop connection for mac" (downloaded from Microsoft website) 2.1 version.

When I run the tool, there is only one textbox for me to input the computer, and click "connect". There is no "option" button or "tab" for me to choose the screen size. And I also can't find any "option" in later steps, so that the window I remotely connected to a win7 system is very small. even if I tried to click the "+" button to maximize the window, if failed and nothing happened.

Any comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft's Remote Desktop Connection for Mac does not have a lot of view options. Once you have connected to a remote computer you can use the items in the Remote Desktop Connection View menu to change the size of window. Your choices are:

- **Command 1**: Fit to Window
- **Command 2**: Full Screen

You probably want to use Command-2 to make the remote desktop as large as possible by having it take over your whole screen. In the non-fullscreen mode, you should also be able to drag the edge of the remote desktop window to make it larger.

Comment: In the Mac's "Microsoft Remote Desktop" application window, you can right click on your remote PC, select Edit, and on the Display tab you can select the resolution, e.g., 1280x960 and then check "Fit session to Window".

Answer (score 10):

Go to Preferences in the RDC Menu or press  +  with the RDC Session active.
Then go to the Display Tab and change the Remote Desktop Size.